# how to convert binary to int using own algorithm python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I would like to convert birnary to in using own algorithm.

Here is the code:

```
binary="" 
decimal=""
while binary!="exit":
    decimal= input(">>")
    decimal = decimal
    if decimal!="0":
        n = len(decimal) -1
        n = pow(n, 2)
        print(n)
```

Input:

```
1010
```

Bad Output:

```
9
```

When I enter binary and check them with calculator they arent true.
I dont have big clue how to make it so sorry for mistakes in code.

Thanks for reply

Comment: Forget about Python for a second -- can you clearly put into words how you would go about doing it by hand? You seem to be trying to write code before you really understand just what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please edit your question to show us an example of your input data and the desired output.

Comment: @MarianD - I think the input/output is fairly obvious, enter '101' and you get '5' out. The issue is the code shown does not come close to performing that conversion.

Comment: Ummm.. 1010 = 10 and 111111 = 63

Comment: I know they arent true, thats the output.

Comment: It's NOT your output, because you have an infinite loop - `binary!="exit"` is constantly `True`.

Comment: @BAt - I thought, in response to MarianD's comment, you posted the _desired_ output, I didn't realise it was the _actual_ output :)

Comment: @m69 - but the `while` loop checks a variable `binary` which is always an empty string

Comment: So your input is NOT as you shown, please edit your question to be precise. Copy/paste your input and your output into your question.

Comment: You need to help us to help you. :-)

Comment: I don't want to offend you, but probably it would be better for you meantime to solve more basic problems. Honestly, it's written between lines of your code. Then you may return to this problem.

Comment: @BAt - Have you single-stepped through your code in a debugger? If you do, you will see why you are getting the incorrect answers. The first comment you received from John said "...can you clearly put into words how you would go about doing it...", this is a good way to code, write comments _first_ as to how you will do it (line by line) and then replace those with code.

Comment: Thanks all for help I firstly need to understand it, than write the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the input (where the user enters a binary number) outside the loop that's processing it. Then you have string containing ones (1) and zeros (0) which you can loop through.

Starting at the right-hand end of the string, multiply that number (1 or 0) by 1 (let's call this multiplier the `ordinal`) and save the result as `total`.

Multiply the `ordinal` by 2.

Grab the next number (from the right) from the input string and multiply it by the `ordinal`, add the result to `total`.

Keep going, multiplying the `ordinal` and using that to multiply the next number from the input string, until you run out of "numbers" in the input string.

Print `total`

Comment: Thanks for answer

Comment: "Thanks" is in SO expressed with *voting up and/or accepting the answer*.

Comment: I would like to vote up but I dont have enough badges for that

Comment: @MarianD - BAt needs [15 rep to be able to vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) an answer. But thanks for trying to get me rep ;)

Answer (score 0):

First off, I think the line `n = pow(n, 2)` might be backwards from what you need. If you're converting binary digits, 2 is the base and `n` will be the power to raise it to, so you'll need `n = pow(2, n)`.

Now, since you want to add up all the digits that are set to 1, you'll also need to add them to a new variable too. If you have more questions about this just ask here, and I'll see how I can help :)

Comment: Thanks for answer, I will try to improve my code.